# Symfony 1and1 Email

Tags: php, symfony

Hello everyone I need help help me it's been 3 days I try to solve the problem but I still have no solution

so here I finished my website create with symfony 4.1 and I want to put it online everything works nickel is nothing to say except one thing

it is the mail send the contact form it works (I test them on another server) but on 1and1 server it does not work

I try everything mailjet gmail all possible smtp help me please I need it for my contact form and for confirmation by mail for FosUserBundle

here are my environment variables

my service.yaml:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_port: 465
mailer_host: auth.smtp.1and1.fr
mailer_user: email@mondoamine
mailer_password: mot de passe
```

et mon .env :

```
MAILER_URL=Mydomaine
```

and my controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/contact")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function contact(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer): Response {

    $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $contact = $form->getData();
        $message = (new \Swift_Message($contact['subject']))
            ->setFrom($contact['email'])
            ->setTo('crowbackend@gmail.com')
            ->setBody(
                $contact['message'],
                'text/plain'
            );
        $mailer->send($message);

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Le méssage a bien étais envoyer vous allez recevoir une réponse d\'ici 48h' );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_front_index');
    }

    return $this->render('contact.html.twig', [
        'title' => 'Contacter Nous',
        'description' => 'Contacter nous a tout moment si vous avez des questions',
        'keywords' => 'Contact, monCpf, info',
        'formContact' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: sounds more like a support ticket for 1&1 rather than SO - if it works elsewhere (SMTP server wise) then it's not a code issue, but a server one

Comment: the code works perfectly on o2switch I call 1and1 but they have not find any solution for my problem

Comment: that's what I'm saying.. the issue is their end, not codes

Comment: they did not bring me much help

Comment: are you on paid support?

Comment: Yes i have 1&1 Unlimited Plus

Comment: then they should be providing better support.. not much we can do I think (someone correct me if I'm wrong :))

Answer (score 2):

I struggled quite a bit to make it work as well. Here are a few tips :

- my working configuration:

  `MAILER_HOST auth.smtp.1and1.fr
  MAILER_USER email@domain.fr
  MAILER_PASSWORD "password"
  MAILER_PORT 587
  MAILER_ENCRYPTION tls
  MAILER_AUTH_MODE login
  MAILER_TRANSPORT smtp`
- double check that your password is not too long. At first mine was 24 characters long and I could not even log in at https://webmail.1and1.fr
- If your password contains special characters, don't forget to add quotes (`"`) around it

Hope it helps someone else out there!